# QGIS2 composer - non-rectangular inset map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'd like to have a near-full-page rectangular map object, then add a non-rectangular inset map object with 6 vertices.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this, other than making two actual maps then brute-force post-processing the images?

Answer (score 1):

Given it's not a standard option - but people have been looking for workarounds, I found this that may guide you:
[Blogpost about the use of SVG-files and Print Composer blending](http://smathermather.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/quantum-gis-compositing-continued/)

Comment: Interesting lead - after fiddling around with svg overlays and blending modes and grouping and raising and lowering and such, I'm not sure how to apply to compositing to get a non-rectangular inset.  Will keep fiddling around essentially with boolean layer operations and such - any ideas?